# Cancel request if taking to long to process

Tags: c#

Hello is this possible in c#:

If I have a loop say:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  x++;
}
```

And it takes more than 1 second to complete, is it possible to kill the code and move on?

Comment: You could wrap the work in a different [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178%28VS.80%29.aspx). _See Also [destroying threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyayh29d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)_

Comment: What about if the code was not in a loop but look more like this:`double a = RandomProvider.Next(2, 5);
            while (a == 3) { RandomProvider.Next(2, 5);}
            double b = RandomProvider.Next(2, 5);
            double c = b /a; 
            double e = RandomProvider.Next(8, 11);
            while (e == 9) { RandomProvider.Next(8,11); }
            double f = b / e;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you have the loop running in a different thread, you can abort that thread from a different thread. This would effectively kill the code you're running, and would work fine in the simplified example you've given. The following code demonstrates how you might do this:

```
void Main()
{
    double foo = 0;
    var thread = new Thread(() => foo = GetFoo());
    thread.Start();
    string message;
    if(thread.Join(1000))
    {
        message = foo.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        message = "Process took too long";
        thread.Abort();
    }
    message.Dump();
}

public double GetFoo() {
    double a = RandomProvider.Next(2, 5); 
    while (a == 3) { RandomProvider.Next(2, 5);} 
    double b = RandomProvider.Next(2, 5); 
    double c = b /a; 
    double e = RandomProvider.Next(8, 11); 
    while (e == 9) { RandomProvider.Next(8,11); } 
    double f = b / e;
    return f;
}
```

However, as you can see from Eric Lippert's comment (and others), aborting a thread is not very graceful (a.k.a. "pure evil"). If you were to have important things happening inside this loop, you could end up with data in an unstable state by forcing the thread abortion in the middle of the loop. So it is possible, but whether you *want* to use this approach will depend on what exactly you're doing in the loop.

So a better option would be to have your loops voluntarily decide to exit when they're told to (**Updated 2015/11/5 to use newer TPL classes**):

```
async void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        var foo = await GetFooAsync(cancelTokenSource.Token);
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process took too long");
    }
}

private Random RandomProvider = new Random();

public async Task<double> GetFooAsync(CancellationToken cancelToken) {
    double a = RandomProvider.Next(2, 5); 
    while (a == 3) 
    { 
        cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        RandomProvider.Next(2, 5);
    } 
    double b = RandomProvider.Next(2, 5); 
    double c = b /a; 
    double e = RandomProvider.Next(8, 11); 
    while (e == 9) 
    { 
        cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        RandomProvider.Next(8,11); 
    } 
    double f = b / e;
    return f;
}
```

This gives `GetFooAsync` an opportunity to catch on to the fact that it's supposed to exit soon, and make sure it gets into a stable state before giving up the ghost.

Comment: +1. I would run the long-running code on a separate thread, and have some UI button wired up to abort that thread.

Comment: last time i looked at pre-emptive processing, threads were pretty much the only option (Timers, ThreadPools, and most other alternatives cannot be forcefully terminated). there may be a new option, Windows Workflow. depending on requirements, either may be a viable option.

Comment: This is a bad idea. If you can't shut down a thread cleanly then either change the architecture until you can, or run the code in another *process*, not another *thread*.  Aborting a thread is pure evil and should only be taken on as a last resort.

Comment: Agree with Eric, Abort can cause lots of trouble

Comment: @oleksii, @Eric Lippert: I was more focused on the "can it be done" aspect than the "should I do it" aspect. Thanks for your comments. I've updated the answer.

Comment: What prevents the jitter or the CPU from optimizing away or reordering the read access to the boolean in your example? It's not marked as volatile, so the C# compiler, the jit compiler and the CPU are all permitted to perform optimizations on it that might make _abort always appear to be false.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Clearly I am not skilled at this sort of thing. What would I need to mark as volatile? The `_abort` field? Also, I found your answer and corresponding blog posting interesting, but I'm curious about strategies that someone might use to make their program better able to voluntarily abort. Do you know of any good articles or other resources along those lines? I've never really had to worry about these aspects in any of my programming thus far.

Comment: There are a variety of techniques. One of the fanciest is in this article by Peter Richie; he develops a new SuspendableThread class that uses a combination of wait handles and interlocked operations to implement cooperative suspension, resumption and termination. I don't know enough about threading to give an informed opinion of its correctness, but Peter Richie is a pretty smart guy. http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2006/10/13/_2700_System.Threading.Thread.Suspend_280029002700_-is-obsolete_3A00_-_2700_Thread.Suspend-has-been-deprecated_2E002E002E00_.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert "either change the architecture until you can, or run the code in another process, not another thread." Both are not very applicable in some situations. ATM I'm debugging a programm which is using an sql driver. The driver is from the database vendor. Programm stops sometimes within the third party dll. For me the best way would be : stop that damn thing if a database fetch takes longer then x ms and just start that very small sql-call again. Putting each fetch to a call to a seperate process would lead to much higher runtimes. Vendor: No exception- no problem - no new version...

Answer (score 5):

If you control the code that needs to be shut down then write logic into it that enables it to be shut down cleanly from another thread.

If you do not control the code that needs to be shut down then there are two scenarios. First, it is *hostile* to you and actively resisting your attempts to shut it down. That is a *bad* situation to be in.  Ideally you should run that code in another process, not another thread, and destroy the process. A hostile thread has lots of tricks it can do to keep you from shutting it down.

Second, if it is not hostile and it can't be shut down cleanly then either it is badly designed, or it is buggy.  Fix it. If you can't fix it, run it in another process, just like it was hostile.

The last thing you should do is abort the thread. Thread aborts are pure evil and should only be done as a last resort. The right thing to do is to design the code so that it can be cancelled cleanly and quickly.

More thoughts:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/22/should-i-specify-a-timeout.aspx

Alternatively, you could go with a single-threaded approach. Break the work up into small chunks where the last thing each chunk of work does is enqueues the next chunk of work onto a work queue. You then sit in a loop, pulling work out of the queue and executing it. To stop early, just clear the queue. No need to go with a multithreaded approach if you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a simple way without mucking around with threading:

```
int x = 0;
int startTime = Environment.TickCount;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    x++;
    int currentTime = Environment.TickCount;
    if ((currentTime - startTime) > 1000)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

You can replace `Environment.TickCount` with a `DateTime` call or `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` if you like.

Comment: Checking the time on every iteration may slow it down too much. It would be better to check only occasionally, every 1000 iterations, for example.

Comment: @MRAB: checking the time on every iteration will slow it down, but checking to see if you're on the 1000th, 2000th etc. iteration will also slow it down somewhat. I was assuming that the asker is really doing more inside the loop than just incrementing `x`, so presumably the time that takes dwarfs the time taken by the `Environment.TickCount` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), this class supports cancellation

Comment: @oleksii, supports voluntary cancellation. cannot be forcefully terminated, ie does not expose an abort method.

Comment: @johnny but user can check if `Cancel` was called in the loop. I would better use `Join` rather than `Abort`, as I think using  `Abort` is a bad practice

Comment: @user459320 yes it does, but it will be a bit tricky, as any threading in a web (in terms of delivering result to the user)

Comment: @oleksii, very true, and solution will depend on requirements. it is unclear if long running process is their code or someone else's. if we are a processing kernel, and must guarantee termination in a timely manner, we do not always have the luxury of trusting executing thread to poll for a cancellation signal. however since original post, it would appear they *are* writing the process code, so they may enforce the poll to their satisfaction :)

Comment: @oleksii, er, regarding `Join` and `Abort`, also correct. graceful termination typically takes the form of a threadsafe cancel signal (eg, a shared `ManualResetEvent`) and a `Join` with a "graceperiod" timeout, which once expired is followed by an 'Abort'.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the number of iteration in the loop more than what you do inside the loop, then you can ask for save the time when the loop started, and see de diference betweeen each iteration ( or maybe %10, 20, 100) and cancel if the time you wanted to spend on that task is over.

Comment: well MusiGenesis is what i was going for.